# get max value of an Auto Increment column in sql

Tags: php, mysql

so i have this code that uploads an image and resize it, and saves both

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   


        $sql="SELECT MAX(event_id) AS event_id FROM evenimente";
        //$result=mysql_query($sql);
        $prefix=mysql_query($sql);


        $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file2=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));                                        
        $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        //
        $sizes = array();
        $sizes['100'] = 100;



        list(,,$type) = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $type = image_type_to_extension($type);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'images/'.$prefix.$type);

        $t = 'imagecreatefrom'.$type;
        $t = str_replace('.','',$t);
        $img = $t('images/'.$prefix.$type);

        foreach($sizes as $k=>$v)
        {

            $width = imagesx( $img );
            $height = imagesy( $img );

            $new_width = $v;
            $new_height = floor( $height * ( $v / $width ) );

            $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
            imagealphablending( $tmp_img, false );
            imagesavealpha( $tmp_img, true );
            imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

            $c = 'image'.$type;
            $c = str_replace('.','',$c);
            $c( $tmp_img, 'images/th/'.$prefix.$type );

        }                                       
        $location="images/" . $prefix.$type;
        $sql="INSERT INTO evenimente (event_data, event_datasf, event_titlu, event_detalii, event_poza) VALUES      ('". $_POST['data'] ."', '". $_POST['datasf'] ."', '". $_POST['titlu'] ."', '". $_POST['detalii'] ."', '$location')  ";
    mysql_query($sql);
    //$prefix =mysql_insert_id();
    include 'include.html';
    echo 'OK!!!<br /> Redirecting';
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;adauga_eveniment.php'>";




}






                                }
```

so the code "works"...i have this problem i need to save the images with `the event_id`. but i can't make `$prefix` memorize the max id from my database and i don't know why...
hope you understand. 
I can't use `mysql_insert_id();` because the id is generated after the aql submission, and i need the prefix before that... and `MAX` doesn't work...
I'm using the `event_id` as primary key...

Cheers

Comment: can you show sample records on the table on your desired result/

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please read about this topic and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is correct: `SELECT MAX(event_id) AS event_id FROM evenimente`

The problem is that you want to know the event_id *before* it exists in the table.

SUGGESTION:

1) "insert" the new row

2) "select"the resulting event_id

3) "update" the row

ALSO:

You're using the old, deprecated mysql API.  Please familiarize yourself with either/both of the new mysqli/PDO APIs.  And please consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).  They're more efficient ... and they help mitigate the risks of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: This makes the most sense, and I believe would have the lowest impact on speed compared to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it that way, try

`$sql="SELECT event_id AS event_id FROM evenimente ORDER BY event_id DESC LIMIT 1";`

But note that this will only give you the event_id of the previous event.

Comment: Then you are trying to print the object. Try using print_r(); to see the real value.